# Mirror every request to cloned application

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2019

Basically what I'm asking for is exactly this: [How to set up IIS request mirroring to staging environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620883/how-to-set-up-iis-request-mirroring-to-staging-environment) but since noone has responded to that thread (and it's been there for years), I'm creating another question.

Explanation:
We have a bug in production which is a very strange issue, probably not even related to the code but we need to nail it anyway. Our only idea is to mirror(duplicate/replay) every request that comes to production, to the staging environment which is basically a copy of production (app+db). This way once we see the bug, we'll, hopefully, see it in both envs which gives us a lot of time to investigate - right now we need to recycle entire production app in order to make it work again.

Is there a way to do this in IIS without making code changes?

Comment: It is impossible to achieve in iis, you can only try to achieve it through code.

Comment: There is never such a thing, so "without making code changes" is impossible.